# nginx conf file: what is <% ... %>?

Tags: nginx

I've seen something like the following in an nginx conf file:

```
<%
    if (registry.hasRootSsl) {
%>
```

What does the `<%` and `%>` mean?  It's difficult to find anything from a google search because these are special characters and not words or phrases.

Comment: Are you sure what you're reading is actually an nginx config file, or is it perhaps some kind of template that is being used to generate an nginx config file? I just Googled for that code and found [this](https://github.com/githubsaturn/captainduckduck/blob/9f02a9ae56f3d881b0c96032d5038d9db750146e/app-backend/src/template/root-nginx-conf.ejs) which appears to be an [EJS](http://ejs.co/) template.

Comment: Nice work, Sherlock!  That's exactly what it is.  I'll check out ejs templates.  Thanks.